# How do i make the image to slide move to the right from left 0,0 position to the end right side?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
      var animate, left=0, imgObj=null;

function init(){

   imgObj = document.getElementById('myImage');
   imgObj.style.position= 'absolute';
   imgObj.style.top = '240px';
   imgObj.style.left = '-300px';
   imgObj.style.visibility='hidden';

   moveRight();
}

function moveRight(){
    left = parseInt(imgObj.style.left, 10);
    if (10 >= left) {
        imgObj.style.left = (left + 5) + 'px';
        imgObj.style.visibility='visible';

        animate = setTimeout(function(){moveRight();},20);

    } else {
        stop();
    }
}

function stop(){
   clearTimeout(animate);
}

window.onload = function() {init();};
   </script>
<img id="myImage" src="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files/radar007339.Gif" style="margin-left:170px;" />
```

What it does is moving one image in the middle of screen from the left side to the center.
But what i wanted it to do is to move the image from the left top corner 0,0 to the end of the right side to the right top border and not to stop but that the image will start moving over again from the right to the left.

I never understood this px values. Now it set to top 240 and left -300. I tried to change it to 0 and 0 but it didn't put it on the left top corner and the image didn't move at all.

How can i change the code so it will start to move the image from top left corner to the right top corner and how can i add more images so it will move them nonstop from left to right like slide ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
    var animate, left=0, imgObj=null, right;

    function init(){

       imgObj = document.getElementById('myImage');
       imgObj.style.position= 'absolute';
       imgObj.style.top = 0;
       imgObj.style.left = 0;
       imgObj.style.visibility='visible';

       right = document.documentElement.clientWidth - imgObj.width;
       moveRight();

    }

    function moveRight(){
        if (left < right) {
            left += 5;
            imgObj.style.left = Math.min(left, right) + 'px';

            animate = setTimeout(moveRight,20); // call moveRight in 20msec
        }
    }

    window.onload = init;
</script>
<img id="myImage" src="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files/radar007339.Gif" />
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/o4ndyzj8/1/)**

And now to your **second question**:

> how can i add more images so it will move them nonstop from left to right like slide ?

You only have to change a little bit of the code so that it will work with multiple images:

```
<script>
    var imgObjs=null;

    function init(){
       imgObjs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
        for(var i = imgObjs.length; i--; ) {
           var imgObj = imgObjs[i];
           imgObj.style.position='absolute';
           imgObj.style.top = 0;
           imgObj.style.display='none';        
        }

       moveImage(0);
    }

    function moveImage(i) {
        var imgObj = imgObjs[i],
            right = document.documentElement.clientWidth - imgObj.width;

        left = imgObj.style.left = 0;
        imgObj.style.display='block';

        function moveRight(){
            if (left < right) {
                left += 5;
                imgObj.style.left = Math.min(left, right) + 'px';

                setTimeout(moveRight,20); // call moveRight in 20msec
            } else {
                imgObj.style.display='none';
                moveImage((i+1)%imgObjs.length);
            }
        }
        moveRight();
    }

    window.onload = init;
</script>
<img src="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files/radar007337.Gif" />
<img src="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files/radar007338.Gif" />
<img src="http://newsxpressmedia.com/files/radar-simulation-files/radar007339.Gif" />
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/o4ndyzj8/2/)**

Comment: friedi and how do i make it to start over again moving from the left to right when it's getting to the right side ? I want it to keep moving nonstop.

Comment: I added the answer to your second question

Comment: friedi it does working great. I'm not sure if to ask here but i have two sub questions please: I have a slideshow of images but since the slidshow is in the middle top of screen the moving image dosen't show it moving over it. How can i make that the moving image/s code will push the slideshow down to the middle of screen so there will be some space between the two slides ? This is my html code: http://jsfiddle.net/o4ndyzj8/1/ And you can see it much clear live on my site: http://newsxpressmedia.com/SlideShow.php and this is the html code in: http://pastebin.com/nsNvZDs2

Comment: Sorry for that maybe you can see how to make that each one will not interrupt the other one.

Comment: You can add `imgObj.style.top = document.documentElement.clientHeight - imgObj.height;` after the line `left = imgObj.style.left = 0;`

Comment: But why do you withdraw the accept state of this answer!? I answered your questions...not a nice way

Answer (score 0):

combine javascript and css transition to get the best result

```
<style>
    img {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;

        transition-property: left;
        transition-duration: 2s;
    }
</style>

<img src="pic.jpg">

<script>
    function animate() {
        var img = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
        var img_width = 100;
        var window_width = window.innerWidth;
        img.style.left = window_width - img_width;
    }

    function init() {
        setTimeout(animate, 1000);
    }

    window.onload = init();
</script>
```